# Blank thumbnails after deleting file keys in Regedit

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, regedit

I'm using Windows 10 and somehow I've set a default association for the file type, so I wanted to change that. I deleted this:`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.db` and `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.db`. Now many other file types have blank white thumbnails. Is it possible to restore deleted keys from the RegEdit (I don't have a backup)? What do you suggest?

Comment: Without a registry backup (and the registry changes so frequently that backups are dubious anyway), you probably need to backup your documents and emails and reinstall Windows.

Comment: You can try to create another user.
The data in these paths has almost no information, I can send you the file to recreate them, but it may not work.

Comment: @RpgBoss if you could send it, I would be grateful

Answer (score 0):

Try to recreate the records, copy this code into notepad:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.db]
@="dbfile"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.db]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.db\OpenWithList]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.db\OpenWithProgids]
"dbfile"=hex(0):
```

File -> "Save As..."
Name: thumb.reg
Change the type to "All files"

Then close all open programs and follow this procedure:

[Clear Thumbnails Cache](https://neosmart.net/wiki/clear-thumbnails-cache/)

Restart your Windows.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try this.